# Triangle Trig and calculus

Tags: calculus, geometry

The square of the side opposite a MUNDANGLE in a triangle is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides added to the product of these two sides multiplied by $\sqrt{3}$. What is MUNDANGLE?

This was an extra credit problem on my test, but my teacher said we had to do it for homework.

If anyone could support me and lead me to through the problem that would be great

Comment: According to Google a mundangle...is nothing. The word doesn't exist in google.

Comment: The law of cosines should handle this.

Comment: Does it give the meaning of "mundangle", @MichaelHardy? Because that's the question...

Comment: I take the question to give a definition of "mundangle": it means an angle whose measure is such that the square of the side opposite it is the sum of the squares of the other two sides divided by the product of the other two sides.

Comment: You guys can't be serious! It's like one of those questions: all gooks are kooks. Some kooks are mooks. Are all gooks mooks?

Comment: Well, that also can be, @MichaelHardy. Indeed. Yet the OP hasn't yet addressed the comments...

Comment: Sorry, I was on the phone, but Michael hardy is correct. It is an angle measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle a^2=b^2+c^2+bc\sqrt3$

Now using [Cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) of triangle, $\displaystyle \cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=\frac{-\sqrt3bc}{2bc}=-\frac{\sqrt3}2=-\cos\frac\pi6=\cos\left(\pi-\frac\pi6\right)$ as $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Wasn't the OP asking what is a mundangle?

Comment: @DonAntonio, I thought it to be a non-English term & the OP was trying to find its value

Comment: Well, that could be possible, I guess...I can't say.

Comment: @user99920, did you want this?

Comment: So it seems a MUNDANGLE has measure 5pi/6

Comment: lab bhatt, yes that helps a lot